# Kotlin Firestore: Task is not being awaited in suspend function?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, task, kotlin-coroutines

I am using RemoteMediator to implement offline-first paging with Firestore.

I am attempting to retrieve documents via two queries. The second query depends on the first query.

However, despite using `await()` on each query, the second query receives the first query as a `Task` still and not a `QuerySnapshot`.

```
class UserRemoteMediator(
    private val networkService: UserApiService,
    private val database: UserDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int, User>() {

    private val userDao = database.userDao()

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, User>
    ) {
        return try {
            val loadKey = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> null
                LoadType.PREPEND ->
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    // ...

                    firestore.collection("users")
                        .whereEqualTo("id", lastItem.id)
                        .get()
                        .await()
                }
            }
            
            val response = firestore.collection("users")
                .orderBy("timestamp")
                .startAfter(loadKey)
                .limit(10)
                .get()
                .await()

            // ...
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea what's going on? And how I can await the first query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you also want to see another approach, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePaginationJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out, where I pass in `loadKey` into the second Firestore query, it needed to be `loadKey?.documents?.get(loadKey.size() - 1)`.